# df.loc causes a SettingWithCopyWarning warning message

Tags: python, pandas, chained-assignment

The following line of my code causes a warning :

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
s.loc[-1] = [5,np.nan,np.nan,6]
grouped = s.groupby(['A'])
for key_m, group_m in grouped:
    group_m.loc[-1] = [10,np.nan,np.nan,10]

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:10: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) this is the recommended way of doing, so what is happening ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to show the complete code from the creation of the df to this line in order for us to assist

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation is slightly confusing.

Your `dataframe` is a copy of another `dataframe`.  You can verify this by running `bool(df.is_copy)`  You are getting the warning because you are trying to assign to this copy.

The warning/documentation is telling you how you should have constructed `df` in the first place.  Not how you should assign to it now that it is a copy.

```
df = some_other_df[cols]
```

will make `df` a copy of `some_other_df`.  The warning suggests doing this instead

```
df = some_other_df.loc[:, [cols]]
```

---

Now that it is done, if you choose to ignore this warning, you could

```
df = df.copy()
```

or

```
df.is_copy = None
```

Comment: is_copy is deprecated. Is there a new technique to use that is "future-approved"?

Comment: `df = df.copy()` should work just fine.  I personally avoid editing dataframes in place.  Each transformation produces a new copy and I overwrite the old one when desired.